# Did Shiva get angry on Mata Sati when she doubted Ram?

Tags: shiva, rama, sati

I watched a youtube video in which a saint was saying that Mata Sati once doubted if Ram is actually the avatar of Vishnu and she went to test him. To which Shiva got angry on Sati and later abandoned her(maybe for small period of time). Because of which she had to go alone in the yagya of Prajapati Daksh, where she immolated herself. Because she didn't get due respect there.

But later Shiva regretted it (abandoning her) a lot.

Is this story true ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually no. Lord Shiva not become angry with Sati when she doubted Rama; Instead he explained Rama's divinity and allowed to test it.

> Śiva said:
>
> 43. O Goddess, if your mind is not convinced, listen to my words. You can test the divinity of Rāma yourself, using your own intelligence.
> 44. O beloved Satī, he is standing there beneath the Vaṭa tree. You can test him and proceed until your delusion is quelled.

**Course**: [Shiva Purana, Sati Khanda, Chapter 24](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226044.html)

I hope the answer clear your doubt.